# Change value of an EditText of another position of a ListView from the Adapter

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a Listview and an adapter. Each row of the Listview has an EditText box.

I want onTextChanged of a text box to set the value of the last row EditText box.

The data of the list consist of an ArrayList of Strings. So each row is a position of the ArrayList.

From the adapter i can modify the value of a specific position of the ArrayList but i don't know how to get a reference for the EditText of a specific position (the last one) in order to set the value.

Any ideas?

Comment: please put your code so someone can better understand your question

Comment: if(position==size of list-1){
editText.setText("What you want");
}
Just a idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a setItems() & getItems() method in your adapter like this:

```
public ArrayList<String> getItems(){
    return this.items;
}

public void setItems(ArrayList<String> items){
    this.items = items;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

In the constructor of the adapter pass the arrayList and save it to a global variable that holds your data(this.items).

Everytime you want to change last row call getItems, modify last row data of arraylist and setItems passing the arrayList, keep in mind calling this for every letter change is pretty inefficient, because the adapter will be looking the data to replace it if needed.